# Unpivot multiple variables in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, unpivot

I've got a big dataframe which shows the amount of each product and their costs for different products. However, I want to transform (unpivot) the dataframe into a long dataframe with each product name as an ID and their amounts and costs in two different columns. I've tried the ‍`pd.melt‍‍‍` and ireshape functions, but neither seems to work.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.
Here is my table

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Year': [year1, year2,year3],                                                                       
               'A': [200,300,400],
               'B': [500,600,300],
               'C': [450,369,235],
               'A cost': [7000, 4000, 7000 ],
               'B cost': [9000, 4000, 6000],
               'C cost': [1100, 4300, 2320],
               })
print(df)
```

current data frame:

[image]

Desired data frame:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create MultiIndex by splitting columnsnames and setting `Year` to `index`, then replace missing values with `amount` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Year': 'year1,year2,year3'.split(','),
               'A': [200,300,400],
               'B': [500,600,300],
               'C': [450,369,235],
               'A cost': [7000, 4000, 7000 ],
               'B cost': [9000, 4000, 6000],
               'C cost': [1100, 4300, 2320],
               })
print(df)
    
df1 = df.set_index('Year')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split(expand=True)

f = lambda x: 'amount' if pd.isna(x) else x
df1 = df1.rename(columns=f).stack(0).rename_axis(['Year','product']).reset_index()
print (df1)
    Year product  amount  cost
0  year1       A     200  7000
1  year1       B     500  9000
2  year1       C     450  1100
3  year2       A     300  4000
4  year2       B     600  4000
5  year2       C     369  4300
6  year3       A     400  7000
7  year3       B     300  6000
8  year3       C     235  2320
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved quite simply with janitor's [`pivot_longer`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer):

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

out = (df
 .pivot_longer(index='Year', names_to=('product', '.value'),
               names_pattern=r'(\S+)\s*(\S*)')
 .rename(columns={'': 'amount'})
)
```

output:

```
    Year product  amount  cost
0  year1       A     200  7000
1  year2       A     300  4000
2  year3       A     400  7000
3  year1       B     500  9000
4  year2       B     600  4000
5  year3       B     300  6000
6  year1       C     450  1100
7  year2       C     369  4300
8  year3       C     235  2320
```